# ANTLR Grammar With Ambiguous Alternatives

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar

My grammar is producing an unexpected result.  I am not sure if it is just my bug or some issues with ANTLR'S ambiguous alternatives processing logic.

Here is my grammar :

```
    grammar PPMacro;
options {
  language=Java;
  backtrack=true;

}

file: (inputLines)+ EOF;

inputLines 
:  ( preprocessorLineSet  |  oneNormalInputLine )  ; 

oneNormalInputLine  @after{System.out.print("["+$text+"]");}  
: (any_token_except_crlf)* CRLF ;

preprocessorLineSet 
: ifPart endifLine;

ifPart: ifLine  inputLines*   ;
ifLine  @after{System.out.print("{"+$text+"}" );} 
:  '#' IF (any_token_except_crlf)* CRLF ;

endifLine @after{System.out.print("{"+$text+"}" );} 
:  '#' ENDIF (any_token_except_crlf)* CRLF ;

any_token_except_crlf: (ANY_ID | WS | '#'|IF|ENDIF);
// just matches everything

CRLF: '\r'?  '\n'  ;
WS: (' '|'\t'|'\f' )+;
Hash: '#'  ;
IF     : 'if'    ;
ENDIF  : 'endif' ;
ANY_ID: ( 'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'| '_')+ ;
```

**Explanation**:

It is for parsing a C++ #if ... #endif block

I am trying to recognize nested #if #endif block. This is done by my *preprocessorLineSet*.  It contains a recursive definition to support nested block.  *oneNormalInputLine* is to handle anything not of the #if form.  This rule is a match anything rule and actually matches a #if line. But I deliberately put it after the *preprocessorLineSet* in *inputLines*.  I'm expecting this ordering can prevent it from matching a #if or #endif line.  The reason to use a catch-all rule is that I want a rule to accept any other c++ syntax and simply echo them back to the output.

I my test, I just print out everything.  Lines matched by *preprocessorLineSet* should be surrounded by {}, while those matched by *oneNormalInputLine* should be surrounded by [].

**Sample inputs** :

```
#if s
s
#if a
s 
s
#endif
#endif
```

and this

```
#if
abc
#endif
```

The corresponding outputs:

```
[#if s
][s
][#if a
][s
][s
][#endif
][#endif
]
```

and this

```
[#if
][abc
][#endif
]
```

**Problem**:

All the output lines including #if #endif are surrounded by [] meaning they are matched ONLY by *oneNormalInputLine*!  But I am not expecting this.  The *preprocessorLineSet* should be able to match the #if lines.  Why'd I get this result?

This line contains ambiguous alternatives:

```
inputLines  :  ( preprocessorLineSet  |  oneNormalInputLine );
```

since both can match the #if and #endif.  But I am expecting the first alternative should be used rather than the later one.  Also note that backtracking is on.

EDIT
The reason my *oneNormalInputLine* rule accepts everything is that it is difficult to express something not having a specific pattern as #if pattern can be rather complicated:

```
/***

comments

*/   # /***
comments
*/ if
```

is a valid pattern. Writing a rule not having this pattern seems difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not really robust - I'd suggest you to keep it simple and use the actual language rule, which says that every line that begins with `#` is a preprocessor directive, and the one that doesn't begin with `#` isn't. There would be no ambiguity in the grammar using this rule and it would be much simpler to understand.

Now why doesn't your grammar work? The problem is that your `preprocesstoLineSet` rule *can't* match anything.

```
preprocessorLineSet 
: ifPart endifLine;

ifPart: ifLine  inputLines*   ;
```

It starts by `#if ...`, then should match other lines, and as the first matching `#endif` comes, it should match it and finish. However, it doesn't actually do that. `inputLines` can match pretty much any line (pretty much - it won't match eg. C++'s operators and other non-identifiers), including all preprocessor directives. That means the `ifPart` rule will match to the end of input and there would be no `endifLine` left. Note that backtracking has no effect on this, because once ANTLR matches a rule (in this case `ifPart`, which will succeed on the whole rest of the input, since `*` is greedy), it will never backtrack into it. ANTLR's rules for backtracking are hairy...

Note that if you made `oneNormalLine` *not* match preprocessor directives (eg. it would be something like `(nonHash any*| ) CRLF`, it would start to work.

Comment: Thx very much. But the problem is I want to ignore #define, #pragma,etc. i.e. not all preprocessor directives are matched by my preprocesstoLineSet. I cannot use a # to tell if a line should belong to preprocesstoLineSet or not. Also C++ allows multiline comment that can span > 1 lines before and after the # i.e "/* spanning many lines */ # /*spanning many lines*/ if" is equivalent to "#if" (see my edit). So writing a rule not having the required pattern seems difficult! Any suggestion?

Comment: You can still ignore `#define` by putting it as another case of `preprocessorLineSet`. The comments would be much better handled in the lexer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `any_token_except_crlf` is causing the ambiguity. You need to fix that (and remove `backtrack=true;`) by letting that rule match the following:

- space-chars;
- a `'#'` followed by anything other than `'if'`, `'endif'` and line breaks;
- any char except `'#'`  and line breaks, followed by a `'if'` or `'endif'`
- an identifier.

A small working example (I named the rules a bit differently...):

```java
grammar PPMacro;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  FILE;
}

file
  :  line+ EOF -> ^(FILE line+)
  ;

line
  :  if_stat
  |  normal_line
  ;

if_stat
  :  HASH IF normal_line line* HASH ENDIF -> ^(IF normal_line line*)
  ;

normal_line
  :  non_special* CRLF -> non_special*
  ;

non_special
  :  WS
  |  HASH ~(IF | ENDIF | CRLF)
  |  ~(HASH | CRLF) (IF | ENDIF)
  |  ID
  ;

CRLF  : '\r'?  '\n'  ;
WS    : (' ' | '\t' | '\f')+;
HASH  : '#'  ;
IF    : 'if'    ;
ENDIF : 'endif' ;
ID    : ( 'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'| '_')+ ;
```

This can be tested with the class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PPMacroLexer lexer = new PPMacroLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("test.cpp"));
    PPMacroParser parser = new PPMacroParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.file().getTree();
    DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
    StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
    System.out.println(st);
  }
}
```

and the `test.cpp` file that might look like this:

```
a b
#if s
t
#if a
u 
v
#endif
#endif
c
d
```

which will produce the following AST:

[image]

### EDIT

I just now saw that you want to account for multi-line comments and spaces between `#` and `if` (and `endif`). You could handle such a thing best in the lexer, like this:

```java
grammar PPMacro;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  FILE;
  ENDIF;
}

file
  :  line+ EOF -> ^(FILE line+)
  ;

line
  :  if_stat
  |  normal_line
  ;

if_stat
  :  IF normal_line line* ENDIF -> ^(IF normal_line line*)
  ;

normal_line
  :  non_special* CRLF -> non_special*
  ;

non_special
  :  WS
  |  ID
  ;

IF      : '#' NOISE* ('if' | 'endif' {$type=ENDIF;});
CRLF    : '\r'?  '\n';
WS      : (' ' | '\t' | '\f')+;
ID      : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_')+;
COMMENT : '/*' .* '*/' {skip();};

fragment NOISE
  :  '/*' .* '*/'
  |  WS
  ;

fragment ENDIF : ;
```

which will parse the following input:

```
a b
# /* 
comment 
*/ if s
t
#    if a
u 
v
#      /*
another 
comment */  endif
#endif
c
d
```

in pretty much the same AST as I posted above.

Comment: why backtrack=true should not be used?

Comment: @JavaMan, in your case, it forces the parser to try and do its utmost best to parse the entire input, resulting in the fact that all your lines are parsed as "normal" lines. If there _are_ ambiguities in a grammar, it's much better to use a couple of look-aheads (syntactic predicates) instead of enabling global backtracking on _all_ rules in your parser grammar (which is what `backtrack=true` does!). Also see this ANTLR Wiki entry: [How to remove global backtracking from your grammar](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/How+to+remove+global+backtracking+from+your+grammar)

Comment: @JavaMan, see my EDIT as well.